# How to download files and folders from Onedrive using wget?

Tags: wget, download, batch-jobs

How to use wget to download files from Onedrive? (and batch files and entire folders, if possible)

Comment: Please take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/833199/in-office-365-how-do-i-get-a-direct-download-link-for-an-excel-document-stored-i "In Office 365 how do I get a direct download link for an Excel document stored in One Drive for Business?" to see if that answers your question.

Comment: But is necessary subscripted account in Office365.

Comment: Use the OneDrive client that someone has kindly written for Linux ?  https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old

Comment: Try to download the file to your browser, while the download is running, right click and 'copy download link'. 

If you are lucky you can wget that link.

Comment: I try Onedrive-d, but couldn't do 'get' work.
Really by copying link to file and put in 'wget', it works, thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using Chrome (but Firefox will probably also work).

1. Open DevTools
2. Click the Download button.
3. Download but cancel immediately
4. Open the 'Network' tab in DevTools. Search for 'Zip?authKey=' in 
   DevTools and open it (click). This is a POST request.
5. Click 'View source' to the right of 'Form data' at the bottom.
6. Construct the command as follows:

```
wget --post-data='<raw form data>' '<Download URL>'
```

Or:

```
wget --post-data='resIds=xxx&canary=yyy&authkey=zzz' 'https://cid--foobar.users.storage.live.com/downloadfiles/V1/Zip?authKey=zzz'
```

This even works on a different host (with a different IP address).

Comment: A simpler variation on this (using Firefox) is: Tools->Web Developer->Network. Find  'Zip?authKey=', right click on it and 'Copy as cURL'. Copy-paste into the command line and add '-o /path/to/some/file'.
Of course this uses cURL instead of wget, but for this purpose they function identically

Comment: @happyskeptic So convenient! It also works on Chrome!

Comment: And how to do it automatically if there’s 100000 files to share?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @happyskeptic I guess something changed on the side of OneDrive. I am doing same thing but with the record which has "x-zip-compressed" in "Type" field.

Comment: Yeah, there was no return for `Zip?authKey=` but I searched for `zip` and it returned a couple of files with gzip in the metadata description. One file appeared to be empty by judging the icon next to the string. The other had what looked like a white piece of paper icon or a file icon next to it so I right clicked on that string and copied it. No need to use any special syntax, I just used `aria2c <url>`

Answer (score 33):

**Update on APRIL 2021:
It looks like this solution NO LONGER WORKS WITH ONEDRIVE FOR BUSINESS.**

There is one way that works for me (based on [How to Make Direct Link of OneDrive Files](https://www.marstranslation.com/blog/how-to-make-direct-link-of-onedrive-files))

1. Right-click on the file you are interested in download (from web interface), and choose Embed.
2. Press *"Generate HTML code to embed this file"*.
3. Copy the part contained in the `""` of src is your link. This will look like <https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E&
   resid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lDqtLG8LqfiA>.
4. Replace `embed` with `download`. This will look like https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E&resid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lDqtLG8LqfiA.
5. Feed it to `wget` using following syntax (the quotes are required):

   ```
    wget --no-check-certificate "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E&resid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lDqtLG8LqfiA"
   ```
6. Enjoy.

Comment: Ok, now everything is in one place)

Comment: One must not forget to put the link in `""` in `wget`. I did and it didn't work.

Comment: @Fedorov7890 It doesn't work. I tried to download a folder.

Comment: It works for files only

Comment: I don't see "embed" when I right-click on files or folders.

Comment: Hello @Fedorov7890 it seems that the embed option is no longer available.

Comment: @Fedorov7890 Sigh. **[THIS DOESN’T WORK WITH ONEDRIVE FOR BUSINESS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#link-types)**.

Comment: I had to add the string `&download=1` at the *tail* of the URL. Example: instead of using `wget --no-check-certificate "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E&resid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lDqtLG8LqfiA"` I had to use `wget --no-check-certificate "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E&resid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lDqtLG8LqfiA&download=1"`

Comment: That's working fine

Answer (score 20):

generate a sharing link and append "&download=1" to the end of it.

e.g. if the link is "https://some.host/:z:/x/personal/some_user/123456asdf?e=12345"

then

```
wget "https://some.host/:z:/x/personal/some_user/123456asdf?e=12345&download=1"
```

Comment: THIS! is the easiest way and it works.

Comment: doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes and should be the selected answer. Especially since OneDrive doesnt offer the embed option for business accounts!

Comment: Works only for publicly exposed files, but great solution!

Comment: tested on 28/10/2022 and it worked!

Answer (score 8):

Also, we can use [CurlWget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/curlwget/jmocjfidanebdlinpbcdkcmgdifblncg?hl=en)
I already tried on OneDrive and Google Drive

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to download an entire *publicly shared folder* (without auth!): [OneDeath](https://gitlab.com/VADemon/onedeath)

It uses wget to do some API calls and will then recursively download files. Bonus: sha1 checks of finished files.

**Sharepoint** is now also supported, but it's a little trickier (it currently fetches more files from a drive than what is shown by the link). A major problem was a slightly different API structure and the fact that the session token expires after 1h, but it's solved too. They also appear to have some rate-limiting in place, so don't start too many parallel downloads.

The script can extract ready-to-use `wget` commands using the `-w` parameter.

PS: If you are interested to know more about the web API, I will give a run down of the process.

Comment: the best answer :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the link in web interface like Chrome.
2. Click "Download" on the top left.
3. At the bottom, click "Show All".
4. Find the downloading or downloaded file, right click the long link and click "Copy Link Address".
5. wget the long address in command line.

Comment: probably the only one working way to download some shared files if you don't want to install additional tools or bring the python code to extract objects

Comment: @Hayden and how to do this if automatically if there’s 100000 files to share?

Comment: @user2284570 Haven't tried that before. Maybe you can try this https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive.

Comment: @Hayden no I really need to have those bunch of generated links accessible by third party tools.

Answer (score 2):

This python SDK (with example) for OneDrive project works (for personal, business, and corporate accounts):

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python

Comment: The project is deprecated and the api it uses is disabled since 2019.

Answer (score 2):

> You can embed the file and Replace embed with a download. This will
> look like
> https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6EBddB03E38A53ED3E&resid=6EBB03Eddd38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lddDqtLG8LqfiA.

**Now use PHP curl to get this file content**

```
$download_url = "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=6EBddB03E38A53ED3E&resid=6EBB03Eddd38A53ED3E%21116&authkey=AC4lddDqtLG8LqfiA"; 
$file_name = "test.xlsx";  
$ch = curl_init($download_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    
 $data = curl_exec($ch);  
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);  
$error = curl_errno($ch);  
curl_close($ch);   // A file with the same name may exist, that must be handled.  $file_save_path =   $file_name;
file_put_contents($file_save_path, $data);    

echo 'File successfully retrieved and stored!';
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually have an alternative solution:

1. set-up OneDrive on you computer. This won't download the files on your local machine so don't need to worry about disk space.
2. open a terminal window in the OneDrive folder on your computer then you can copy the contents of a specific folder like this:

```bash
cp -r <MY_BIG_ONEDRIVE_FOLDER>/ <MY_DESTINATION_FOLDER>
```

Where `<MY_BIG_ONEDRIVE_FOLDER>` is the name of the OneDrive folder you want to copy files from and `<MY_DESTINATION_FOLDER>` is the destination folder.

I'm actually using this approach right now while I'm writing this post to copy +200Gb of files from my OneDrive folder to my external hard-drive.