# How to download a folder from Onedrive business using wget?

Tags: files, wget

I've tried the "wget --no-check-certificate 'https://my.sharepoint.com/cid=6EBB03E38A53ED3E?donwload=1" -O name' " to download a folder from OneDrive business. But it turns out that this approach only works for downloading a single file, but not a folder. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is "donwload " a typo for download?

Comment: Have you tried `wget -r --no-parent ....`?

Comment: Sorry, it's typo.

Comment: Yes, I've tried  -r --no-parent, but it doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344721/117549

Comment: @Lynn you may need to export your cookies and reference that in a cURL command to be able to download folders as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924014/download-file-folder-from-sharepoint-using-curl-wget-automatically).

Comment: Tried, thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried the cookies, but it doesn't work, I guess it's because mine is business version, but personal. Thanks.